# Не могу изменить параметр layout_margin

Tags: android, android-layout

При попытке вызвать код:

```
btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button1);
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn1.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, 0, 0, 1);
btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button2);
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn2.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(1, 0, 1, 0);
btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button1);
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btn3.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

У кнопок не меняется параметр `layout_margin` (они как были все "слитые", так и остались). Что тут не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могу сказать одно, что они стали на 1 пиксель дальше друг от друга, вы должны привыкнуть, что в коде вы работаете только с пикселями. конечно можно переводить dp в пиксели конкретного телефона программно, но для этого надо использовать отдельные методы. Таким образом вы поставили отступы по 1 пикселю, поэтому вам кажется, что они рядом.

Comment: Тогда ответьте на один из вопросов:

1. Как указывать размер в dp/sp?
2. Как создать background для кнопки? Точнее, как в ``selector`` засунуть ```layout`` параметры?

Comment: @bukashka101 вообще 2-ой пункт уже не относится к этому вопросу, но так называемый `selector` понимает параметры `inset` и `padding` для указания отступов. Точнее не сам селектор, а подключаемые к нему графические примитивы.

Comment: А это что такое?О.о

Comment: @bukashka101 Попробуйте для начала потаращить глаза куда-нибудь в документацию андроид, ладно. Там все доступно разъясняется.